# while starting mysql in in xamp and opening php my admin on browser its giving errors giving several errors

Tags: mysql, database

[image]
while running mysql its giving error can anyone help

[image]
While opening on browser its showing this error

Comment: We need contents of Windows event viewer to understand the cause of the shutdown.

Comment: Ok I'll give you the content